# Excel: Update Line plot based on dynamically changing column length

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I am line plotting data in excel based on data on a column. However, the amount of data in this column may change (it's length may change) and I want the graph to update to only included values in the updated length of the column.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Supposing your data starts at ("A1"), you could do the following:

`ActiveWorksheet.Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xldown))`

You can read more about `.End` [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/range-end-property-excel)

Furthermore, you can utilize `.End` to dynamically append new values to the existing list using `.Offset(1, 0)` where the first parameter = column; second = row.

For instance, say we want to add the Integer 5 to our existing list:

`ActiveWorksheet.Range("A1").End(xldown).Offset(1, 0).Value = 5`

Comment: Hey dipper, thank you for the feedback. My values are being appended by external software program to a specific column that I have selected. Where do enter the "ActiveWorksheet.Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xldown))" ?

Comment: This entirely depends on your use-case and what you're trying to achieve. If you can give some more insight I can help better. At which point do you want to update your selection? After each time a value is added from the external source? After an Excel button click? There are many situations.

Comment: Hey Dipper, the column of values I have change entirely once I input a "circuit" number. Essentially, I have data for how much amperage is running through over 300 circuits. I have created an excel sheet in such a way that once I enter in a circuit number the amperage values during certain times for that circuit is loaded into an excel column from an external software program. However, the amount of rows for the column changes with each circuit. I want to find a way for excel to graph all the data points in the column once the circuit changes.

Comment: Ok, well the code I gave you above should be enough to select all values from column A1 (change to fit your needs). With that, you can wrap it inside whatever sub/event you are using to action updates and it'll grab the dynamic range for further analysis. Anything else, let me know.